# Why this (?=^\s*)print_debug positive lookahead is not matching the \s* spaces?

Tags: python, regex, sublimetext3, regex-lookarounds

#### Why this `(?=^\s*)print_debug` positive lookahead is not matching the `\s*` spaces?

The full regex pattern is `(?=^\s*)print_debug`. And the sample matching is:

```
print_debug('scroll set: '+str(position));
print_debug('scroll set: '+str(position));
                print_debug('scroll set: '+str(position));
                print_debug('supposed current scroll: '+str(view.viewport_position())); # THIS LIES
            else:
                print_debug('SKIPPED...')
```

However it is only matching the first two lines:

[image: Only matching the first two lines]

Here is the link to a online regex engine:

1. https://regex101.com/r/RIIqTg/1

---

#### Why the `\s*` are being ignored when used with `^`?

1. If you remove the `^`, the `\s*` start matching.
2. If you add the `^`, the `\s*` stop working.

I want it to use on `Sublime Text` and disable all debugging statements from my `Python` source code files for the Sublime Text packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Root cause

The `(?=^\s*)` is a *positive lookahead* that matches the start of a line (in SublimeText, the `^` matches the line start by default), and then 0+ whitespaces (i.e. the `\s*` does not have to match *any* text at all!).

Thus, your `(?=^\s*)print_debug` pattern matches `print_debug` if it is at the start of the string (note the `(?!^)` works the same way as `(?<!^)` as the `^` is a zero-width assertion).

## Solution

Since there is no variable-width **lookbehind** support in SublimeText regex, you can leverage the **`\K` match reset operator**:

```
^\s*\Kprint_debug
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FmiKiY/1)

**Details**:

- `^` -  start of a line
- `\s*`  - zero or more whitespaces (may be replaced with `\h*` to only match horizontal whitespace)
- `\K` - omitting the whole text matched so far
- `print_debug` - a literal string.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I believe it's actually your positive lookahead that's messing it up, not the `^`.  I think what you actually want is an atomic group(http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html):

```
(?>^\s*)print_debug
```

That shows a match for me on every line (and I even tested it in Sublime).

Comment: Your is matching all the new line and its spaces. It cannot match them for the correct replacements.  https://regex101.com/r/FmiKiY/3

Answer (score -1):

`(?=^\s*)print_debug` means that at a matching position not only `print_debug` has to match, but also `^\s*`.

The matching position has be the beginning of a "print_debug" and the beginning of a line with optional white space. So only "print_debug" at the beginning of a line matches.

If you want to ensure that `print_debug` is *preceeded* by only white space, you should use a look-behind instead: `(?<=^\s*)print_debug`

Comment: Your lookbehind is not working: * A quantifier inside a lookbehind makes it non-fixed width, https://regex101.com/r/FmiKiY/2

Comment: Yeah seems like in this regex flavor you can't use variable width matches in lookbehinds...